# how to use default video application in iphone through objective c

Tags: iphone, video

how to use default video application in iphone through objective c. 
I want to used default video application of iphone in my application as I have already used default camera before but facing issues for video.

Comment: please  explain your Question bit more.how to activate video camera or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the MobileCoreServices framework to your project

Add `#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>` to the header file where you will reference the picker. 
Alternately, you can add the import to your precompiled header file (.pch) so the UTCoreTypes constants are available throughout the project.

Now, before calling the `UIImagePickerController`, just set the mediaTypes property to the movie type, `kUTTypeMovie`. Or, if you wanted to only display photos you would use `kUTTypeImage`:

```
myImagePickerController.mediaTypes =  
 [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
```

Keep in mind that you should check if the device supports video recording before setting the sourceType, as setting it to a movie type on a device that does not support video recording will cause all sorts of havoc. You do that by looking at the available source types:

```
NSArray *sourceTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:myImagePickerController.sourceType];
if (![sourceTypes containsObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie ]){
   // no movie type supported...add code to handle that here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you're referring to the [media layer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html) frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

To on Video camera using  code

UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
imagePicker.mediaTypes =[UIImagePickerController  availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];                imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode=UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;

}
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

}
    else    {
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No Camera Device" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
    }